# Filename without certain certain expressions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file, which includes the following rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?:(?!teaser_).)*\.(jpg|jpeg).*)$ watermark.php?img=$1 [NC]
```

Right now, it applies a watermark on every .jpg or .jpeg image, which doesn't include "teaser_" in it's name.

How do I edit it so that it doesn't affect images with "teaser_" OR "original_" in the filename?

so image 127_1386.jpg should be affected, original_127_1386.jpg should NOT be affected and teaser_127.jpg should also NOT be affected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make regex complicated. Use it like this with a separate `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(teaser|original)_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.jpe?g)$ watermark.php?img=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```